# How to use gpio7 & 8

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio

I have a python script which uses board pins 7 & 8 but when I try to set the pins to output an exception occurs.

```
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD);        
    GPIO.setup(7,GPIO.OUT);
    GPIO.setup(8,GPIO.OUT);
```

ValueError: The channel sent is invalid on a Raspberry Pi

I already disabled spi and i2c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pin 8 is UART TxD. This is used for console output, and is owned by root.

To use, you really need to disable `console` and `ttyAMA0` in `/boot/cmdline.txt` and `/etc/inittab`

Comment: Tried this already and it worked. Guide can be found here: http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/raspberry-pi-serial-port